# If else Statement in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, if-statement

I'm a newbie at swift, so how do I add an extra else if statement saying greater than 56 & less than 65 to my button?

The button work fine, it just need one more additional statement added to finished up my coding.

```
@IBAction func Submit4Button(sender: AnyObject) {

        let a: Float? = (EnterH4Dimension.text as NSString).floatValue

        if a > 65 {

            self.DimensionLabel.text = " Cameron H4 With Guide Pins."

            yesButton.hidden = false
            noButton.hidden = false

            emailButton.hidden = true
            DimensionLabel.hidden = false

            self.view.endEditing(true)

        }

        else if EnterH4Dimension.text == "" {

            noButton.hidden =  true
            yesButton.hidden = true

            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Dimension", message: "Missing Data Input.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        else {

            self.DimensionLabel.text = "Dimensions meet guideline"

            noButton.hidden =  true
            yesButton.hidden = true

            DimensionLabel.hidden = false
            shallowDimButton.hidden = true
            emailButton.hidden = false
            self.view.endEditing(true)

        }

    }
```

Comment: else if a > 55 && < 65 { }, that what I have written so far, but run into an error.

Comment: You have already added an `else if` clause… you just have to do the same. What's special about it anyway?

Comment: @Coder now that's a syntax error. Think about that. The `<` operator takes **two** operands. You have to say **what** you want to be less than 65. `else if a > 55 && a < 65`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to `a`:

You can try the following:

```
else if a > 56 && a < 65  {}
```

Depending on whether or not you want to include 56 and 65 you can use `<=` & `>=`

Note that all your `else if` statements should be place before the final `else` statement

Comment: I don't think i need the <= & >=.

Comment: can you have two else if statement?  for example ...if , else if, else, else if?  I am assuming it have to be if, else if and else.

Comment: all your 'else if' must before the final 'else' statements

Comment: you should not add it after the final else, but just before.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realized the additional 'else if' have to be before the 'else' statement.  That definitely solved my problem.  Thank!